# Typings es6-promise give 'no dependencies' as output

Tags: meteor

I had tried to install typings es6-promise like step 0 angular2-meteor:
http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping
But when i run `'typings install es6-promise --save'`, it was return 
Es6-promise |_ (No dependencies)
Have problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it simply means that the `es6-promise` package is stand-alone and does not depend on any other package.

You can list your installed packages using:

```
$ typings ll             

└── es6-promise
```

and make sure it is what you expected.